# Get information on how to call a method from the module/class path

Tags: python-3.x, class, methods, python-module

In many documentations, instead of giving the actual command on how to call a method or function, the path to the respective method is listed (e.g.`networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx` instead of `nx.draw()` (that is a path, right?)) I find that annoying as I sometimes have to extra look up examples where the actual command is then shown.

Is it possible to get the information on how to call a function from the given path? Something like:

```
help(networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. In python that is called introspection.

For example:

```
import pandas as pd

print(dir(pd))
```

this would show you all the methods in the pd module.

Then if you want to know how to use a certain method you would use:

```
import pandas as pd

print(help(pd.DataFrame))
```

NOTE: If you don't see anything helpful, it means there may not be clear documentation, in which case you can go to pypi.org, search for your module then look for the documentation (though the code above reflects the documentation on that site). IF that fails, stackoverflow is your best friend :)